# What kind of wire-to-board connector is this?

Tags: connector, pins

It has a pitch of approximately 3.9 mm. Pins are 1.1 mm square. On the board there are 2 and 3 pin versions of this connector.

Here are a few pictures:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: By "quadratic" you mean "square", right?

Comment: Yes, the shape is square. The area is quadratic...

Comment: In English we'd say a 'rectangle' or 'rectangular'. Mein Deutsch ist nicht sehr gut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Connectors of that style are known as MTA156 connectors. The pin pitch is 0.156 inches (156 mils). Several manufacturers support this type but the original was AMP which is now known as TE Connectivity.

The square pins of the headers are 0.045 inches (45 mils) in dimension.

Here is a connector image taken from the [Mouser online electronics retailer](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-AMP/3-640426-3?qs=sGAEpiMZZMvvAo%252bip5liN6QGh2%2FUCtAw).

[image]